# How can a native macOS app programmatically run a shortcut from Apple's Shortcuts app?

Tags: macos

Given the name of a shortcut in Apple's Shortcuts app, or some other way of identifying a shortcut, how can a native macOS app run it?

This would be the equivalent of executing the following shell command:

```
shortcuts run "Shortcut name here"
```

Granted executing a shell command is a possible way of doing this, but I'm hoping that using an API function will be better since they generally allow for better control and error handling. For example, the shell command doesn't provide any easily obtained error code for the calling process when something goes wrong, but rather displays a system notification with the error code.

edit: So far searching online and Apple's docs, as well as looking at the external symbols in Apple's `shortcuts` command line utility, suggests there is currently no public API for this. If so then then executing a shell command is probably the only way to do this. I'll leave this question open in case this is incorrect or it eventually changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by executing an URL:

shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=Shortcut%20name%20here